# Show only a specific page div Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have this code:

```
     <?php if(!is_home()): ?>

   <div id="cristi"><?php echo get_the_content(1); ?></div> 


                     <?php endif; ?>


                      <?php if(is_page(19)); ?>

 <div id="contact2"><?php echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="54" title="Contact form 1"]' ) ?></div> 


                     <?php endif; ?>
```

I want to display a div only a page with ID 19.

I used is_page() function but not working.

Can you help me solve this problem please?

This is the site:

http://avocat.dac-proiect.ro/wp/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you have a semi colon here: `<?php if(is_page(19)); ?>`  instead of a colon `:`

Answer (score 0):

is_page(ID) must be used outside [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) in order to work properly, as defined here:

> This Conditional Tag checks if Pages are being displayed. This is a boolean >function, meaning it returns either TRUE or FALSE. This tag must be used BEFORE >The Loop and does not work inside The Loop (see Notes below).

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page

```
$is_contact = is_page(19);

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 

// do stuff
if ($is_contact)
    // output contact form

endwhile;
```